# Django TypeError at /signup/ 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a signup form that verifies if the email field contains gmail and gives an error if not.

forms.py

```
def clean_email(self):
    submitted_data = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if '@gmail.com' not in submitted_data:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You must register using a gmail address')
```

views.py

```
class SignUpView(View):
form_class = SignUpForm
template_name = 'user/register.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False # Deactivate account till it is confirmed
        user.save()

        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = 'Activate Your Account'
        message = render_to_string('user/account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        user.email_user(subject, message)

        return redirect('confirm_registration')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

I want to add few other 'trusted emails' so the form will allow users to register for instance: @yahoo.com, @outlook.com but I cannot add a list or tuple because I get an error:

```
TypeError at /signup/
'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

**Question**
How can I create a list of trusted email domains and instead '@gmail.com' put list of email domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `list` of trusted email services and check for your `submitted_data` i.e. `email` in your case contains any of the email services. You can try this.

```
def clean_email(self):
    submitted_data = self.cleaned_data['email']
    trusted_email_services = ["@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com", "@outlook.com"]
    if not any(email_service in submitted_data for email_service in trusted_email_services)
        raise forms.ValidationError('You must register using a gmail or yahoo or outlook address')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like you are trying to do something like:
`if ['a', 'b'] in 'string'`? I believe `in` can only check if a single item on the left is in an iterator on the right.
So for this to work you would have to have a single item on the left of your `in` rather than a list.

Have you tried something like this?

```
if not any(email in submitted_data for email in ['@gmail.com', '@otheremail.com']):
    raise YourError
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am still getting 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list error

Comment: Sorry what I wrote there is completely wrong, I will edit now